Why does Vertex AI Search return results locally but none when deployed to Google Run?
I'm using Google Vertex AI Search to power an AI experiment on Google Cloud Run (both services are in the very same Google Cloud project.
For an unknown reason, my code fetches successfully Vertex AI Search data locally, but returns nothing when deployed to Google Cloud Run. Error response gives no help.
Any idea?
My search function (heavily inspired from Google documentation):
const { SearchServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/discoveryengine').v1beta

export const search_context = async (keywords: string) => {
    try {
        const projectId = '123456789'
        const location = 'global'
        const apiEndpoint = 'discoveryengine.googleapis.com'
        const collectionId = 'default_collection'
        const dataStoreId = 'datastore-html'
        const servingConfigId = 'default_search:answer'
        const searchQuery = keywords
        const client = new SearchServiceClient({ apiEndpoint: apiEndpoint })

        const name = client.projectLocationCollectionDataStoreServingConfigPath(projectId, location, collectionId, dataStoreId, servingConfigId)

        const request = {
            pageSize: 2,
            query: searchQuery,
            servingConfig: name
        }

        const IResponseParams = {
            ISearchResult: 0,
            ISearchRequest: 1,
            ISearchResponse: 2
        }

        const response = await client.search(request, {
            autoPaginate: false // Must disable autoPaginate to avoid iterate through all pages
        })

        const knowledge = []
    
        const results = await response[IResponseParams.ISearchResponse].results
        
        console.log(results)

        for await (const result of results) {
            const rx = result.document.derivedStructData.fields.chunks.listValue.values
            for await (const r of rx) {
                console.log(r.structValue.fields.content.stringValue)
                knowledge.push(r.structValue.fields.content.stringValue)
            }
        }

        return knowledge
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

Locally:
results =
[
  {
    modelScores: {},
    id: "P1vlqbKxBRb0L1LWwVcn",
    document: {
      name: "projects/123456789/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores/datastore-html/branches/0/documents/P1vlqbKxBRb0L1LWwVcn",
      id: "P1vlqbKxBRb0L1LWwVcn",
      schemaId: "",
      derivedStructData: [Object ...],
      parentDocumentId: "",
      content: null,
      indexTime: null,
      structData: [Object ...],
      data: "structData",
    },
  }, {
    modelScores: {},
    id: "7t8WnRzzeBIOq7HzwEoD",
    document: {
      name: "projects/123456789/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores/datastore-html/branches/0/documents/7t8WnRzzeBIOq7HzwEoD",
      id: "7t8WnRzzeBIOq7HzwEoD",
      schemaId: "",
      derivedStructData: [Object ...],
      parentDocumentId: "",
      content: null,
      indexTime: null,
      structData: [Object ...],
      data: "structData",
    },
  }
]

And my r.structValue.fields.content.stringValue are chunks of text.  This is perfect.
But when deployed to Google Cloud Run, for the very same query results =
[
  {
    modelScores: {},
    id: "",
    document: null,
  },
  {
    modelScores: {},
    id: "",
    document: null,
  }
]

and logically TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'result.document.derivedStructData')
Do you have any clue?
Thanks.
